# Actualizar campo automáticamente en registro según evaluaciones periódicas

Tags: sql, mariadb

No se si es posible en MariaDB pero tengo esta tabla llamada permisos donde guardo los permisos con sus determinadas limites de fecha:

[image: Tabla Permisos]

Inicialmente quería usar un Trigger para evaluar si es que la actual fecha era mayor que f_fin, esto haría que p_activo cambiara de 1 a 0, para asi no tener que estan actualizando manualmente ese campo todas las veces, pero me di cuenta que el Trigger solo funcionaria si realizaba alguna acción en la tabla, como un insert, updata o delete:

si (fecha actual > f_fin) hacer p_activo = 0

Saben si existe alguna funcionalidad de MariaDB o de SQL que permita evaluar automáticamente registros dentro de una tabla y que según determinada expresión lógica actualice otro campo ese mismo registro.

Comment: ¿Te referís a los [eventos](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/events/#example)?

Comment: Si!, gracias, tu comentario  me ayudo. Aunque hay que tomar en cuenta sobre una variable de entorno que hay que activar para que los eventos se ejecuten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final creé un evento que se ejecuta diariamente para poder evaluar si desactivar un permiso.

```
CREATE EVENT desactivarPermisos
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  UPDATE permisos SET p_activo = 0 WHERE NOW() > f_fin;
```

Aunque hay que considerar que si no se activa esta variable en la base de datos el evento nunca se ejecutara.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes usar son las [columnas calculadas](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/), que pueden ser persistentes (necesario si intervienen en índices) o virtuales (no físicas). La idea es asociar a una columna de la tabla un criterio o condición que establece el valor de forma dinámica.

```
create table Prueba (
  f_fin    datetime,
  p_activo int AS (f_fin > curdate()) VIRTUAL
);

insert into Prueba(f_fin) values ('2024-03-20');
insert into Prueba(f_fin) values ('2024-03-01');

select *, curdate() from Prueba;
```

| f_fin | p_activo | curdate() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-20 00:00:00 | 1 | 2024-03-06 |
| 2024-03-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2024-03-06 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jqagauuq)

En este ejemplo `f_fin > curdate()` se evalúa al momento de ejecutar la consulta y para cada fila en este caso.